# Compare a string to a range of integers

Tags: c#, string, char, int

I have two integers, say 4 and 11, and I have a string for example Month04

I want to able to compare that string to the range of numbers between 11 and 4.

So in the other ways a loop which has (if Month04.contains(11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4) then

How can I solve that elegantly?

Regards

Comment: Could you tell us more about your string? Will it always be formatted like "Month" + number? Are there different variations? Would something like "July" be a valid entry?

Comment: What if the string was `"Month14"`? That contains `4`... (yes, I know there are not 14 months)

Comment: `bool MonthContainsNumberInRange(string month, int min, int max) { for(int i = min; i <= max; i++) if (month.Substring(month.Length - 2).Equals(i.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')) return true; return false; }` should work if the month always ends in a two-digit number as in your example, `"Month04"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `any()` to check if the number exists in the string and `Enumerable.Range()` to create the numbers list

```
string month = "Month04";
int num1 = 4;
int num2 = 11;

IEnumerable<int> numbersList = Enumerable.Range(num1, num2 - num1 + 1) ;
if (numbersList.Any(x => month.Contains(x.ToString())))
{
    // then
}
```

Comment: But I need to add these numbers automatically, I mean the numbers are variables. I can create a loop to fill the int list, is that a good suggestion?

Comment: @NedalAbdouni see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a generic method for this:

```
public static bool CheckNameInRangeOfIntegers(int lowerBound, int upperBound, string inputString)
{
    List<int> rangeOfIntegers=Enumerable.Range(lowerBound,(upperBound-lowerBound + 1)).ToList();
    return rangeOfIntegers.Any(x=>inputString.Contains(x.ToString()));      
}
```

[Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mj0VkW) can be called as :

```
Console.WriteLine(CheckNameInRangeOfIntegers(4,11,"Month4")); // true
Console.WriteLine(CheckNameInRangeOfIntegers(4,11,"Month1")); // false
```

Please note: Be clear about your scenarios, if you are processing with `.Any()` followed by a `.Contains()` then you will be in trouble in some cases, for example, `lowerBound = 1`, `uppeBound=10`, and `inputString="Month11"`

Comment: What are the values in `rangeOfIntegers`

Comment: This did it, thank you!

Comment: Why do you want that range if OP is entering upperbound and lowerbound of list then your ranges should be inbetween. right? correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar: correct..! thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your all months ends with digits then you can try below,

```
int startIndex = 4;  //I used variables to define starting index and end index
int endIndex = 11;

List<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(startIndex, (endIndex-startIndex + 1)).ToList();
if (numbers.Any(x => "Month04".EndsWith(x.ToString())))
{
    //Your business logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another example using the Regex pattern `\d+` which will match every digit group in the string (`04` in this case). Then we can cast those matches to integers, and finally, Linq expressions `Intersect()` and `.Any()` will return `true` if any matching values exist between the two integer collections.

```
string s = "Month04";
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"\d+");
var numbersInString = pattern.Matches(s).Cast<Match>().Select(x = int.Parse(x.Value));

int lowerBound = 4;
int upperBound = 11;
var range = Enumerable.Range(lowerBound, upperBound - lowerBound + 1);

if (numbersInString.Intersect(range).Any())
{
    //Match
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4 };
string str = "Month04";

int number = int.Parse(str.Replace("Month", ""));
if (numbers.Contains(number))
{
    Console.WriteLine("YEEE!");
}
```